# Remainder when divided by 75

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem:

Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $\dots$ be the increasing sequence of positive numbers which are co-prime to $75$ ($x_1$ = 1, $x_2$ = 2, $x_3$ = 4, $x_4$ = 7, $\dots$). Find the remainder when $x_{2019}$ is divided by 75.

Can't get started. Haven't got the faintest idea on how to approach.

Hints?

Comment: Do you mean "the" increasing sequence of positive numbers which are co-prime to $75$?

Comment: What have you tried? Is $x_n$ the smallest number that will fit (i.e. there are no omissions)?

Comment: (This also reminds me of the _Countdown_ episode where a contestant says "I'd like to multiply by $75$"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the positive integers coprime to 75 in order, not just any sequence of integers where they are all coprime to 75 (otherwise the answer can be any integer coprime to 75)

There are $\varphi(75) = 40$ residues mod 75 coprime to 75. Hence the sequence has period 40.

Hence $x_{2019} = x_{2019 (mod 40)} = x_{19}$, which you can easily find by hand.

Comment: The last sentence needs some justification

Comment: I think you might have been thinking $\equiv \pmod{75}$ for the first $=$ sign in the last paragraph, because it is certainly false that $x_{2019}=x_{19}$.